# How to get RealmList inside Thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, arraylist, realm

Hi in my app i need to get RealmList from RealmObject(PlayList.class). The problem is that i trying to do this on other thread.(some loop engine with tick() method) So my solution it was to get the RealmList from the RealmObject and convert it to ArrayList and than do with it what i want in any thread.

This is the crash i get

```
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
```

this is my RealmObject class

```
public class PlaylistModel extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

    public int id;
    public String path;
    public String fileName;
    public String duration;
    public RealmList<Note> notes;
```

this is my Note class

```
public class MidiModel extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

    private String tag;
    private long spaceTime = -1;
```

and this is how i get the data

```
public RealmResults<PlaylistModel> getPlaylist(){
    realm.beginTransaction();
    RealmResults<PlaylistModel> realmResults = realm.where(PlaylistModel.class).findAll();
    realm.commitTransaction();
    return realmResults;
}
```

and this is how i trying to read the RealmList in a diffrent thread

```
  public void tick(){
        Note model =  noteList.get(index);
        index++;
    }
```

How can i make it works?
Do i need to convert RealmList to ArrayList Before manipulate? 
Please help :)

Comment: 1.) you don't need a write transaction in order to read  2.) you need to open a Realm instance on the background thread, query the object with that Realm instance, and at the end of the thread you need to close the Realm

Comment: But what if I'm using Dagger for getting the realmInstance ?

Comment: Same rules apply. Typically I have a ref-counted UI instance and obtain a new instance per background thread

Answer (score 1):

Managed RealmObjects cannot be passed between threads, so you need to re-query it on the background thread by its primary key, from a Realm instance that was opened for that thread.

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadedPool(); // like new Thread().start();

public void doSomething(final String pkValue) {
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) { // beginning of thread
                doThingsWithMyObject(realm, pkValue);
            } // end of thread
        }
    }
}

public void doThingsWithMyObject(Realm realm, String pkValue) { // <-- pass Realm instance
    MyObject myObject = realm.where(MyObject.class).equalTo("id", pkValue).findFirst(); // <-- requery
    RealmList<Note> notes = myObject.getNotes();
    // ... do things with notes
}
```